# How do I exclude a matching line and the line that precedes it?

Tags: shell, grep

In my project, I want to exclude some content in `a.txt`.

The content in `a.txt` is:

```
3085180 nscc135 PEND  intelg_sma gcn01                   *_D4d_5.sh Dec 14 14:32
The user has reached his/her job slot limit;
3085182 nscc135 PEND  intelg_sma gcn01                   *_C3v_5.sh Dec 14 14:32
The user has reached his/her job slot limit;
3085184 nscc135 PEND  intelg_sma gcn01                   *_C3v_5.sh Dec 14 14:33
The user has reached his/her job slot limit;
3085186 nscc135 PEND  intelg_sma gcn01                   *_D4d_5.sh Dec 14 14:33
The user has reached his/her job slot limit;
3095798 nsgg289 PEND  intelg_sma gcn03                   400./      Dec 19 09:51
One of the user's groups has reached its job slot limit;
3096822 nsgg289 PEND  intelg_sma gcn03                   460./      Dec 19 18:00
One of the user's groups has reached its job slot limit;
3098784 nsgg289 PEND  intelg_sma gcn04                   xhzha      Dec 20 14:48
One of the user's groups has reached its job slot limit;
3099298 nsgg276 PEND  intelg_sma gcn01                   Pd3.2      Dec 20 18:11
The user has reached his/her job slot limit;
3099299 nsgg276 PEND  intelg_sma gcn01                   Pd2.8      Dec 20 18:12
The user has reached his/her job slot limit;
3099311 nsgg276 PEND  intelg_sma gcn01                   Pt1.8      Dec 20 18:40
The user has reached his/her job slot limit;
3099312 nsgg276 PEND  intelg_sma gcn01                   Pt2        Dec 20 18:41
The user has reached his/her job slot limit;
```

I want to exclude this line containing the content of `The user` and the previous line.
I have tried:

```
grep -A 1 -v "The\ user" a.txt
```

and

```
grep -AB 1 -v "The\ user" a.txt
```

But they both failed.

The correct result should be:

```
3095798 nsgg289 PEND  intelg_sma gcn03                   400./      Dec 19 09:51
One of the user's groups has reached its job slot limit;
3096822 nsgg289 PEND  intelg_sma gcn03                   460./      Dec 19 18:00
One of the user's groups has reached its job slot limit;
3098784 nsgg289 PEND  intelg_sma gcn04                   xhzha      Dec 20 14:48
One of the user's groups has reached its job slot limit;
```

Comment: Try `fgrep -B1 -v "The user" a.txt`

Comment: I have tested, but it doesn't work

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean.  I think the appropriate tool for the job isn't bash, but perhaps Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `-A` and `-B` work the way you're expecting with `-v`. It will not "also exclude" the previous or next line. As such, I do not believe there is a solution to your problem using only `grep`.

One approach is to get the line numbers of the lines containing your pattern, and the lines immediately preceding them. Then, use `sed` to delete those line numbers:

```
grep -n -B 1 'The user' a.txt | egrep -v '^-' | sed -r 's/^([0-9]+).*/\1d/' | sed -f - a.txt
```

Result:

```
$ grep -n -B 1 'The user' a.txt | egrep -v '^-' | sed -r 's/^([0-9]+).*/\1d/' | sed -f - a.txt
3095798 nsgg289 PEND  intelg_sma gcn03                   400./      Dec 19 09:51
One of the user's groups has reached its job slot limit;
3096822 nsgg289 PEND  intelg_sma gcn03                   460./      Dec 19 18:00
One of the user's groups has reached its job slot limit;
3098784 nsgg289 PEND  intelg_sma gcn04                   xhzha      Dec 20 14:48
One of the user's groups has reached its job slot limit;
```

Explained:

```
grep -n -B 1 'The user' a.txt  # Print each line matching 'The user' and one line preceding it, the -n flag prefixes output with line number
egrep -v '^-'                  # The use of grep -B causes grep to separate match groups with '--', we want to disregard those lines
sed -r 's/^([0-9]+).*/\1d/'    # Extract the line numbers and with them create sed delete commands 
sed -f - a.txt                 # and finally feed those commands to sed, operating on your input file
```

Comment: Yes, but i have to write a script file for it. thank you

Comment: SUSE Linux Enterprise and bash shell.

Answer (score 1):

It also works just using `sed`:

```
sed -e 'N;s/\n/####/;/The user/d' -e 's/####/\n/g' a.txt
```

Result:

```
3095798 nsgg289 PEND  intelg_sma gcn03                   400./      Dec 19 09:51
One of the user's groups has reached its job slot limit;
3096822 nsgg289 PEND  intelg_sma gcn03                   460./      Dec 19 18:00
One of the user's groups has reached its job slot limit;
3098784 nsgg289 PEND  intelg_sma gcn04                   xhzha      Dec 20 14:48
One of the user's groups has reached its job slot limit;
```

First, use `N;s/\n/####/;/The user/d` to combine two lines with `####`, and delete line with `The user`; Then call `s/####/\n/g` to split the matched line to two lines.